# Dialogflow v2 api - triggering intent with an event conflicts with input context

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have a couple of intents in my agent that I'd like to trigger either via a training phrase and input context or via an event.

So far, it seems like having an input context on my intent prevents it from ever being triggered by an event.

If I remove the input context, I cant trigger it just fine.

I don't see anything in the docs about the input context and events being mutually exclusive.  Has anyone else seen this?  Any good workarounds?

Comment: can you show how the intents look like and some conversation flow between user and bot?

Comment: The intents have 1 input context and simple affirmative training phrases (e.g. yes, yep, etc).  I'm using a single event that I've defined. 
The easiest way to test is just to create an intent that is triggerable by an event - test it to ensure it's working, then add an input context to the intent, it will no longer be triggerable by the event.

Answer (score 0):

This is the intended behavior, since it allows you to use contexts to control which intent is triggered by a given event.

This is necessary in some situations, for example when using more than one [Carousel](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#carousel) with [Actions on Google](http://actions.google.com/), since all carousels invoke the `actions.intent.OPTION` event and you will need to use contexts to distinguish between them.

To ensure your intent matches when an event is triggered, just set the appropriate context programmatically at the time that you trigger the event.